# Cannot set button background color using styles.xml

Tags: android, css, xml

This looks easy enough but i don't know why i'm not able to do this. This is how i want to style my button:

Resource file

```
<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
    android:text="Login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="EditTextTheme">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But somehow the background color is still default which is grey although the text has already change color to white.
Why did this happen? And how i can overcome this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try style attribute instead of theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
```

Do

```
style="@style/ButtonTheme"
```

on your `<Button`>

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my app colours are set in res/values/themes.xml so I deleted the styles.xml I created and continued with changes in themes.xml. This worked for me. No styles.xml needed.